# How do I get a UDF based on cell color to auto update in excel

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I found a UDF that calculates the values of a cell based on their color. It worked perfectly the first time that I used it. However, now when I change the color of a cell (the color dictates if the cell has been planned or executed), in the existing workbook it does not auto-update. See code below:

```
Function SumByColor(CellColor As Range, rRange As Range)
Application.Volatile True
Dim cSum As Long
Dim ColIndex As Integer
Dim cl As Variant
ColIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each cl In rRange
  If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColIndex Then
    cSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cl, cSum)
  End If
Next cl
SumByColor = cSum
End Function
```

I have tried `Application.Volitale`, but no luck. F9 works to update the cells that house the function. Though, it would be better to auto-update in case I get busy, or walk away from my WS. Any ideas?

Comment: Was `Application.Volitale` a typo in the question for `Application.Volatile`, or was the typo in your original code and that's part of the reason why it didn't work.  (As far as I know, changing the colour of a cell won't force Excel to do a recalc, so I doubt if `Volatile` will help anyway.)

Comment: Changing cell colors does not trigger calculation, or any other event.The way I see it, you can try using `Worksheet_SelectionChange`, or create a macro that repeats itself (say each second) and triggers the calculation.

Comment: What is updating range CellColor? You only want to update SumByClor when that range changes colour. You say "or walk away from my WS". What are you running that makes that cell change colour while you are away from your desk? Whatever it is, can you make it recalculate the worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a worksheet event proc that will run when a change is recognized on the sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 
    'Call function with appropriate variables
End Sub
```